# Laws of motion while climbing a rope

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, string

I'm a little confused with the application of laws of motion on a man climbing a rope. Suppose a man of mass Mg is climbing a rope with an acceleration a. Rope is massless. Now if look through the frame of the piece of rope held by the man, there is a force Mg downward by man, ma downward applied by man and T upward. This balances out as the piece is at rest. This equation is correct, though my way of looking at it maybe incorrect. Now if we look through the man's frame, we have Mg downward, T upward, ma upward the reaction by rope, and as we are in an accelerated frame, ma downward. What am I doing wrong and can you explain how is the man able to climb upward i.e. how the forces are acting to give this motion.

Comment: You understand it perfectly. The tension provides an upward force of $mg+ma$. That is how the man is able to go up the rope. In the man's frame you have an additional non-inertial force of $ma$ pointing downwards as you say, so the man does not accelerate in his own frame.

Comment: What if we just look at the man through an inertial frame. We'll have T upwards, Mg downwards, ma upwards by the rope, sum of these force gives us acceleration of man in the upward direction so = ma, this equation is clearly wrong, where am I wrong?

Comment: @jatin, what do you mean by "ma upwards by the rope"?  The only force the rope exerts on the man is T.    I'm not sure what equation you find wrong.

Comment: Try to convert the system into another similar system, i.e. you can replace the rope by stick with grooves(teeth like gears) and replace the hand pulling by rotating gear trying to climb up the grooved stick

Comment: Just to confirm, is the man climbing upward or dowward?

Comment: Minor note, Mass is $M$ and weight is $M g$.

Comment: You have to use an _intertial frame_ for the equations of motion to be valid without having to resort to adding fictitious forces for things to work out.

Answer (score 0):

If a man moves one hand  up very fast he will not be pulled down  by gravity as he will using the strength.      Of both hands to grip the rope again.If a man moves his hand up slowly gravity will pull him down as he is now gripping the rope with one hand

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! Could you please clarify your answer as i can't quite make sense of it at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Your question looks a bit confusing, but still I would try to answer it (as per my understanding of the question). Clearly in any frame of reference the only force that are acting on the object are:

- Gravitational force on the man,$F_g$
- <s>Tension from the rope, $T$</s> (See the note)
- Static Friction (from the rope, assuming that he is moving upward by pulling ),$f_s$
- <s>ma</s>

**Inertial Frame**

Now these forces act together to cause a net acceleration $a$. The net force is then $ma$ ( Yes! the man does not apply this force its just the effect of all the other forces.).

Therefore the equation can be written as $$F_g + f_s = ma $$.

**Non-Inertial Frame**

Here you just have to account for the pseudo force $-ma$ and the net force equation is as follows:
$$F_g + f_s - ma =m0=0$$.

Hope this clarifys your confusion.

---

**NOTE**

I have not considered the question with the following picture in my mind

[image]

If that isn't the case but like the one in which the man is attached to the rope and is being pulled up then you must consider tension and erase friction from the term.

Answer (score 0):

All answers are wrong here. Actually, the question can be analyzed with just a fragment of rope.

Tension can never act on man. Tension can only act on rope. So, the only possible Free Body Diagram is for a fragment of rope.

Comment: I challenge someone to prove that Tension can act on the man or in any way effect the force applied by the man.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: So, the man can just float up against gravity without any external upward force?

Comment: I agree, The friction between the person's hands and the rope is what motives the person and not the tension on the rope. Just as it is friction that motivates a car and not the engine torque. Just add grease to the rope and see how you can't climb it regardless of the tension. Please [edit] your question to elaborate a bit more without attacking other answers. Just let your viewpoint stand on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to view this from a non-inertial reference frame is not recommended as it would involve additional fictitious forces. If you were reviewing footage from a go-pro camera on the person's head and saw the earth accelerating away from under the person as they moved up the rope you would need to account for a huge force that moved the earth away and the calculation for the tension to do this would yield nonsensical results.

So looking at this from a person standing on the ground, you notice that the rope does not move and so the sum of forces acting on the section of rope where the person is holding it should amount to zero.

There are three forces at play in the rope. The tension from the section of rope above the person, the tension (if any) from the section of rope below the person, and the force of pulling that the person is exerting *downwards* as they climb.

Due to Newton's 3rd law, the same pulling force is acting *upwards* on the person, and then it overcomes gravity the person is going to accelerate upwards.

Mathematically the above is expressed with the following two equations representing Newton's 2nd law on each part.

$$ \begin{aligned}
  T_{\rm above} - F_{\rm pull} - T_{\rm below} & = 0 & & \text{rope segment}\\
  F_{\rm pull} - M g & = m a & & \text{person} \\
\end{aligned}$$

If you assume positive acceleration upwards $a>0$, then it means that the person is pulling more force than their weight $$F_{\rm pull} > M g$$

Once $F_{\rm pull}$ is established the tension on the rope above the person is calculated with

$$ T_{\rm above} = T_{\rm below} + F_{\rm pull}$$

Note that there is a *limit* on how much pulling force can be exerted. This limit can be due to friction, or the mechanical carabiner used to climb.

What would happen if the rope has greased up and down and is thus very slippery? Regardless if the tension on the rope, the amount that a person call pull would be severely limited.